# how to convert string "1157903" to decimal "1.157903"

Tags: python, string, decimal

I want to know how to convert a string with no decimal points into a decimal point, such as converting "1157903" to "1.157903" in python

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know where the decimal point goes? Does the local matter -- some use commas instead of periods for this sort of thing for example.

Comment: basically, i am trying to figure out how to get input from a user, for example "11578930" and convert that to look like this, "11.1M"

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @Lie, yes, [this is X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994553/how-do-i-take-input-such-as-11578903-and-show-output-as-11-5b-in-python)

Comment: integer = raw_input('Input: ') if integer.isdigit() and (float(integer)) >= 1000000 and (float(integer)) < 1000000000: decimal = str(float(integer)/1000000) final = str(decimal)+'M' print (final) elif (integer.isdigit() and (float(integer)) >= 1000000000 and (float(integer)) < 1000000000000): decimal = str(float(integer)/1000000000) final = str(decimal)+'B' print (final) else: print (int(integer)) integer = raw_input('Input: ')

Answer (score 4):

```
s = "1157903"
s2 = '{}.{}'.format(s[0],s[1:])
```

Comment: basically, i am trying to figure out how to get input from a user, for example "11578930" and convert that to look like this, "11.1M"

Answer (score 2):

Couple of more ways:

```
>>> s = '115793'
>>> s[0] + '.' + s[1:]
'1.15793'
```

and

```
>>> s = '115793'
>>> '.'.join([s[0], s[1:]])
'1.15793'
```

Update based on the comment you added to your question:

```
from bisect import bisect

_METRIC_PREFIXES = [  # must be in ascending order for bisect
   ( 0,   ''),  # <blank>
   ( 1, 'da'),  #  deca
   ( 2,  'h'),  #  hecto
   ( 3,  'k'),  #  kilo
   ( 6,  'M'),  #  mega
   ( 9,  'G'),  #  giga
   (12,  'T'),  #  tera
   (15,  'P'),  #  peta
   (18,  'E'),  #  exa
   (21,  'Z'),  #  zetta
   (24,  'Y'),  #  yotta
]

_BREAKPOINTS = tuple(10.**item[0] for item in _METRIC_PREFIXES)

def format_numeric_string(s, prec=1):
    v = int(s)
    i = bisect(_BREAKPOINTS, v)-1
    d = _BREAKPOINTS[i]
    s = _METRIC_PREFIXES[i][1]
    return '{:.{prec}f}{suffix}'.format(v/d, suffix=s, prec=prec)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import random
    randigit = lambda: random.choice('123456789')
    n_digit_string = lambda n: ''.join(d for _ in xrange(n) for d in randigit())

    for s in (n_digit_string(prefix[0]+1) for prefix in _METRIC_PREFIXES):
        print '{:,d} --> {}'.format(int(s), format_numeric_string(s))
```

Sample output of different length random numeric strings:

```
3 --> 3.0
18 --> 1.8da
389 --> 3.9h
3,765 --> 3.8k
2,152,457 --> 2.2M
1,965,289,562 --> 2.0G
7,624,947,619,324 --> 7.6T
7,424,298,578,879,224 --> 7.4P
5,546,663,458,831,949,667 --> 5.5E
4,794,459,711,325,322,715,236 --> 4.8Z
9,992,885,249,921,967,199,174,883 --> 10.0Y
```

Comment: How do i take input such as "11578903" and show output as "11.5B" in python? I am trying to convert a large number into an abbreviated version of it's form. "123456789101112" would become "123.4B". I am truncating the number after the decimal point instead of rounding the decimal point.

input: 1000000 output: 1M

input: 2500000.34 output: 2.5M

input: 532 output: 532

input: 1123456789 output: 1.1B

Thanks.

Comment: How would I convert a decimal to one decimal place and then convert this back to a string?

Comment: Sorry, am not totally sure what you mean. The `format_numeric_string()` function in my answer returns a single string like you describe along with a suffix. You could return them separately by modifying the last line of the function to be `return '{:.{prec}f}'.format(v/d, prec=prec), suffix`.

Answer (score 0):

`"1.157903"` isn't a decimal, it's a string.

Are you looking to convert a string to a number, or the string representation of a number to a string with a decimal in it?

If it's the former, then:

```
>>> s = '115793'
>>> float(s) / 10 ** (len(s) - 1)
1.15793
```

Otherwise:

```
>>> '{}.{}'.format(s[0], s[1:])
'1.15793'
```

Another method to avoid copying strings is to use a `bytearray`:

```
>>> ba = bytearray('12345')
>>> ba.insert(1, ord('.'))
>>> ba
bytearray(b'1.2345')
```

Comment: basically, i am trying to figure out how to get input from a user, for example "11578930" and convert that to look like this, "11.1M" or "1157893000" to "1.5B"

Answer (score 0):

New clarification, new answer. I'd likely approach it like this:

```
import math
SUFFIXES = ['', 'K', 'M']

def convert(s):
    num = s[:len(s) % 3 or 3]
    return '{}{}'.format(num, SUFFIXES[int(math.ceil(len(s) / 3.0) - 1)])

In [1]: from n import convert
In [2]: print convert('123')
123
In [3]: print convert('123123')
123K
In [4]: print convert('12123')
12K
In [5]: print convert('123123123')
123M
```

You can figure out the decimals by a combination of this and other answers.